# Evaluating a multidimensional integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I am solving a physics problem and ended up with the following integral:

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} exp(-\beta\sum_{i=0}^{N}|\vec{r}_{i+1}-\vec{r}_{i}|^2)dr_{0}dr_{1}...dr_{N+1}$ where $\beta\,$ is just a constant, and I am having some difficulty with evaluating the integral, I tried to do the following substitution $u = \vec{r}_{i+1}-\vec{r}_{i}$ but was not very helpful. any help would be appreciated.

Edit: The physics problem I am solving is:

The Hamiltonian of (+2) interacting classical particles, that are enclosed in a cube of volume  at temperature , is given by:

$H = \sum_{i=0}^{N+1} \frac{|\vec{P_{i}}|^2}{2m} +\frac{1}{2}mw^2 \sum_{i=0}^{N}|\vec{r}_{i+1}-\vec{r}_{i}|^2$

Assuming that $\lt{|\vec{r}_{i+1}-\vec{r}_{i}|^2\gt} \,\, \lt\lt \sqrt[3]{V}$ for $0\le i\le N+1,$ Compute the following:

a) The partition function of the sysytem

b) $<|⃗_{+1}−⃗_{0}|^2>$

My Approach:

$Z = \sum exp(-\beta H), where \,\beta = K_{B}T\,$ but in this case since $\lt{|\vec{r}_{i+1}-\vec{r}_{i}|^2\gt}  \lt\lt \sqrt[3]{V}$ we can approximate the sum as an integral, So we will have:
$\int exp(-\beta\sum_{i=0}^{N+1} \frac{|\vec{P_{i}}|^2}{2m}dP_{i})\int exp(-\beta\sum_{i=0}^{N}|\vec{r}_{i+1}-\vec{r}_{i}|^2 dr_{i})$

Comment: Are the $r_i$ numbers or vectors? If they are vectors, why do you integrate them over the real?

Comment: Why did the substitution not work? At first glance there don't seem to be issues.

Comment: @klirk because when you carry out the above substitution there will be two consecutive integrals that depend on u, but I want a substitution two make the integrals independent (if it is possible) and I can’t think of one m.

Comment: Could you write this down? If I set $u_{i+0}=r_{i+1}-r_i$ and $u_0=r_0-r_N$, then this is a liner change of coordinates, so the Jacobian is just a number. So the integral becomes a product of gaussians. I have to ask again though, what do you mean with integrating your vectors from $-\infty$ to $\infty$

Comment: @klirk I mean that each vector could have any magnitude and could be in the positive or negative direction

Comment: If you work on a more than one-dimensional space, then there are more directions than "positive and negative". Do you want to integrate them over the whole space? Do you agree, that the substitution leads to $\pm \int_{\mathbb R^3} \exp(-\beta \sum |\vec u_i|^2) du_0 \dots du_N$? Btw, I just realized that in the original integral, you dont integrate over $r_0$ and $r_{N+1}$, is this intended?

Comment: @klirk Yes I agree that the substitution fixes my problem, and I need to integrate over $r_{0} and r_{N+1}$ just made a mistake, I edited the question, and thanks for your time.

Comment: Glad I could help. Maybe I will post a detailled answer this evening, but I think you should be alright.

Comment: Maybe there is another mistake in your integral. Currently it seems to diverge. There are $N+1$ summands in the exponent, but you integrate $N+2$ variables. Or in the substituted integral, the integrand is independent of $u_0$. A natural way to fix this is to add another summand $|r_0-r_{N+1}|$ (as I already had in mind when defining $u_0$, just messed up the index), but I don't know if this still corresponds to your original question.

Comment: @klirk I think changing $u_{0} = r_{0} - r_{N+1} $ should fix the problem

Comment: No it does not. Even though you should do this, I just messed up the index here. In the substituted integral, the sum runs from $|u_1|^2$ to $|u_{N+1}|^2$ but you still integrate over $u_0$.

Comment: @klirk maybe I should define $u_{i}  = r_{i+1}-r_{i}$

Comment: The problem is not that the substituted integral diverges, it's that the original integral already does.

Comment: @klirk maybe I should rethink my integration limits because they depend on the physics problem I am solving

Comment: Please include the physics problem in the question